# Stuck with type hints in clojure for generic class

Tags: generics, clojure, type-hinting, clojure-java-interop, apache-flink

I am trying to get a small example from Apache flink running in clojure, but right now I am stuck, because of the type hinting in clojure and some strange quirk in flink.

Here is my code:

```
(ns pipeline.core
 (:import
 (org.apache.flink.api.java ExecutionEnvironment)
 (org.apache.flink.api.common.functions FlatMapFunction)
 (org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple Tuple2)
 (org.apache.flink.util Collector)
 (java.lang String)))

(def flink-env (ExecutionEnvironment/createLocalEnvironment))

(def dataset (.fromElements flink-env (to-array ["please test me"])))

(defn tokenizer [] (reify FlatMapFunction
                 ( flatMap [this value collector] 
                   (println value))))

(.flatMap dataset (tokenizer))
```

If I do not provide type hints, I get an error from the flink api:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The types of the interface org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FlatMapFunction could not be inferred. Support for synthetic interfaces, lambdas, and generic types is limited at this point.
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.getParameterType(TypeExtractor.java:662)
```

If I provide type hints:

```
(defn tokenizer [] (reify FlatMapFunction
                 ( ^void flatMap [this ^String value ^Collector collector] 
                   (println value))))
```

I get an error from the clojure compiler:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find matching method: flatMap, leave off hints for auto match.
at clojure.lang.Compiler$NewInstanceMethod.parse(Compiler.java:8065)
```

Is there a way to add type hints in clojure with generic classes?
It should be something like this:

```
(defn tokenizer [] (reify FlatMapFunction
                 ( ^void flatMap [this ^String value ^Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> collector] 
                   (println value))))
```

But that doesn't work. Any ideas?

The lein config looks like this:

```
(defproject pipeline "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
 :description "FIXME: write description"
 :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
 :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
        :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
 :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]               
             [org.apache.flink/flink-java "0.9.0"]              
             ]
  :aot :all)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clojure cannot handle reflections, thus you need to specify the return type manually via Flink method `returns`.

```
(.returns (.flatMap dataset (tokenizer)) String)
```

Furthermore, you need to use `deftype` to define `tokenizer` and instantiate a new object when using it because Flink cannot handle anonymous classes:

```
(deftype tokenizer [] FlatMapFunction
                      (flatMap [this value collector] 
                        (println value)))

(.flatMap dataset (tokenizer.))
```

Here is a **full "Word-Count-Example"** that can be packed into a jar and executed.

Pay attention to the type hints and casts. For `tokenizer` output `(int 1)` is required, otherwise `Long` would be the second type of `Tuple2`. Furthermore, we use a String to declare the output type for `tokenizer` (a class type is not sufficient because the reflection types must also be specified). Finally, we need to type hint `(int-array [0])` to resolve the overload of `groupBy` (without it, the method is ambiguous to the Clojure compiler).

```
(ns org.apache.flink.flink-clojure.WordCount
 (:import
 (org.apache.flink.api.common.functions FlatMapFunction)
 (org.apache.flink.api.java DataSet)
 (org.apache.flink.api.java ExecutionEnvironment)
 (org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple Tuple2)
 (org.apache.flink.util Collector)
 (java.lang String))
 (:require [clojure.string :as str])
 (:gen-class))

(def flink-env (ExecutionEnvironment/createLocalEnvironment))

(def text (.fromElements flink-env (to-array ["please test me and me too"])))

(deftype tokenizer [] FlatMapFunction
                      (flatMap [this value collector]
                        (doseq [v (str/split value #"\s")]
                          (.collect collector (Tuple2. v (int 1))))))

(def tokens (.returns (.flatMap text (tokenizer.)) "Tuple2<String,Integer>"))

(def counts (.sum (.groupBy tokens (int-array [0])) 1))

(defn -main []
  (.print counts)
)
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that didn't help, I still get the exception for 
`    The types of the interface org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FlatMapFunction could not be inferred.`
But thanks for your input, I will look into SingleInputUdfOperator some more.

By the way it should be 
  `  (.returns (.flatMap dataset (tokenizer)) String)`

Comment: So, I tried the same in java directly. I modified the wordcount example, so that the Tokenizer only implements "FlatMapFunction" (without generics). Even using ".returns("Tuple2<String, Integer>") I get the same exception. So perhaps I need to write an additional java wrapper for my purpose that handles the generic types.

Comment: Hi, I just had a closer look and what I suggested should work. It is a bug in the system. I just opened a JIRA for it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-2557 I guess, right now, you need to go the way with the additional Java wrapper.

Comment: Hello Matthias, thanks for your cooperation. I will try to get on with a java wrapper for now.

Comment: Hi, the bug in now fixed in the current master. I just updated my answer (including a full word-count example).

Comment: With the string type hint [deprecated in Flink 1.1](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/SingleOutputStreamOperator.html), @MatthiasJ.Sax, do you have any ideas on how to implement this using the alternative `TypeHint` method signatures?

Comment: I guess not at all... Clojure cannot handle Java generics AFAIK. You would need to define a custom class `MyType extends Tuple2<String,Integer>` and use this instead (you can omit `returns` at all, because for the custom "MyType" Flink will be able to determine the return type automatically.)

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up to this comment [Stuck with type hints in clojure for generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122495/stuck-with-type-hints-in-clojure-for-generic-class?newreg=8bc2be801e0e48aebd7825dcc7c57d6b#comment64251283_32123656)

With the latest flink versions (tested on 1.6.1), you need to define a custom class otherwise you'll get an error like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: returns for class org.apache.flink.api.java.operators.FlatMapOperator, compiling:(WordCount.clj:69:13)
```

custom class:

```
package org.apache.flink.java;

import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;


public class WordCountTuple extends Tuple2<String, Integer> {

}
```

clojure code

```
(ns org.apache.flink.clojure.WordCount
  (:import
   (org.apache.flink.api.common.functions FlatMapFunction)
   (org.apache.flink.api.java DataSet)
   (org.apache.flink.api.java ExecutionEnvironment)
   (org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple Tuple2)
   (org.apache.flink.java WordCountTuple)
   (org.apache.flink.util Collector)
   (java.lang String))
  (:require [clojure.string :as str])
  (:gen-class))

(def flink-env (ExecutionEnvironment/getExecutionEnvironment))

(def text (.fromElements flink-env (to-array ["please test me and me too"])))

(deftype tokenizer [] FlatMapFunction
         (flatMap [this value collector]
           (doseq [v (str/split value #"\s")]
             (.collect collector (Tuple2. v (int 1))))))

(def tokens (.returns (.flatMap text (tokenizer.)) WordCountTuple))

(def counts (.sum (.groupBy tokens (int-array [0])) 1))

(defn -main []
  (.print counts))
```

working example fork here https://github.com/guillaume/flink-external